# Finding an exact match over several rows

Tags: t-sql

I have a table `GroupsTable` that can be described through a MWE as follows.

```
GroupID  MemberID
1        42
2        42
2        43
3        42
3        43
3        44
```

I am then given another table `MemberTable` that contain some rows with `MemberID`. For example:

```
MemberID
42
43
```

The query I need is one that finds the matching `GroupID` that has exactly the `MemberID` from the second table, no more no less. I believe the following code is working, but it is terribly slow, so is there a better way to find the answer?

```
select c.GroupID from (
  select g.GroupID 
  from GroupTable g 
  join MemberTable m on m.MemberID = g.MemberID
  group by g.GroupID
  having count(*) = (select count(*) from MemberTable)
) c 
left join GroupTable x on x.GroupID = c.GroupID
and x.MemberID not in (select MemberID from MemberTable)
where x.GroupID is null
```

Sample data:

```
create table MemberTable (
  MemberID int
)
insert into MemberTable
values 
(42), 
(43);

create table GroupTable (
  GroupID int,
  MemberID int
);
insert into GroupTable 
values 
(1, 42), -- only one member
(2, 42), -- both members
(2, 43), 
(3, 42), -- one member too many
(3, 43),
(3, 44),
(4, 40), -- two irrelevant members
(4, 41);
```

There is a fiddle available here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad818a306600286433634fa83c3628a0

Comment: I took the liberty of adding an edge case to the sample data you've provided. My answer also handles this edge case. (also updated the fiddle)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the fiddle and adding the edge case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of left join, group by, having, and count distinct, like this:

```
DECLARE @Count int;
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM MemberTable;

SELECT GroupID 
FROM GroupTable As G
LEFT JOIN  MemberTable As M
    ON G.MemberID = M.MemberID
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT G.MemberID) = @Count 
AND  COUNT(DISTINCT M.MemberID) = @Count
```

The left join ensures you'll get all the records for each group id.

The count of distinct of the groups member ids ensures you will only get the group ids that does not have have member ids that doesn't appear in the members table.

The count distinct of the members table ensures you will not get groups that happen to have the same number of member ids as the members table.

**Update**

After testing with temp tables on my own environment, I've confirmed my suspicion that the performance killer is the count(distinct). I've changed my query to get rid of it and now it seems to be almost twice as fast as the query in the question:

```
DECLARE @Count int;
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM MemberTable;

SELECT GroupID 
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT GroupID, MemberID
    FROM GroupTable
) As G
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT MemberID
    FROM MemberTable
) As M
    ON G.MemberID = M.MemberID
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT(G.MemberID) = @Count 
AND  COUNT(M.MemberID) = @Count;
```

Note that if the `MemberTable` is known to always have distinct MemberID values you can get rid of the second derived table and simply left join the first derived table to the `MemberTable` directly.

Comment: Thanks @zohar-peled, that seems to work as well, but according to the "Actual Execution Plan" its query cost is twice that of the query in the original post.

Comment: Is there a missing index suggestion in the execution plan (If there is one, it would be in green text at the top part of the results window)

Comment: No, but adding primary keys `primary key (GroupID, MemberID)` and `primary key (MemberID)` actually makes the OP query three times faster. Switching the order of the first primary key it's still twice as fast.

Comment: Ok, back to the drawing board... :-)

Comment: Thanks! I am satisfied with that :)

Comment: Glad to help :-)